# C++ PNG Decoder Error

Tags: c++

I am trying to use [this png decoder](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng), but I'm getting an error with this basic example code:

```
const char* path = "image.png";
int height = 256, width = 256;
vector<unsigned char> image;
unsigned error = lodepng::decode (image, unsigned(width), unsigned(height), path);
```

[image: error message]

I'm not sure what is causing this, since it's almost identical to [this example](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/examples/example_decode.cpp) from the repo.

Comment: Please paste the text of the error in your question.  Don't make it a challenge to read your question.

Comment: Try to *build* it first, and then copy-paste the full and complete (including informational messages) into the question body, as text and unmodified. The full error message from the compiler should include the arguments that was expected, and as such will help us (and *you!*) to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: The width and height are taken by-ref so you can't cast them there.

Comment: My code does match with it, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @user3684950 no, your code does not match the declaration of `decode()`, which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: "The width and height are taken by-ref so you can't cast them there." That was the issue, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound rude, but if you actually compiled the source and read the full error message, you should have found that out in shorter time than it took to write the question itself. The editor and its code-insight or intellisense or whatever might not always tell you all you need to know, only by attempting to build you will get the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. You are not passing in the correct parameters that `decode()` is expecting.

Look at the actual declaration of the `decode()` overload that you are trying to call (there are 3 overloads available):

```
unsigned decode(std::vector<unsigned char>& out, unsigned& w, unsigned& h,
                const std::string& filename,
                LodePNGColorType colortype = LCT_RGBA, unsigned bitdepth = 8);
```

In particular, notice that the 2nd and 3rd parameters are passed by **non-const references**.  Your code is declaring `int` variables that are type-casted to `unsigned` when passed to those parameters.  The compiler would have to create temporary `unsigned` variables to hold the values, but temporaries cannot bind to non-const references.

So, your code DOES NOT match the declaration of that `decode()` overload (or any of the overloads, for that matter).  Hence, the error message that no overloads of `decode()` can be found that accept the parameters you are passing in is correct.  And, if you actually read the error message more carefully, it shows you the argument types that the compiler detected, which you can clearly see do not match the declaration of the `decode()` overload you are trying to call.

You need to change your `width` and `height` variables from `int` to `unsigned`, and get rid of the type-casts:

```
const char* path = "image.png";
unsigned height = 256, width = 256;
vector<unsigned char> image;
unsigned error = lodepng::decode (image, width, height, path);
```